# github event to jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-github-plugin

I have a GitHub webhook triggering a Jenkins pipeline job. I've set 2 events that triggers the webhook (like pull requests and deploy).

Once my Jenkinsfile triggered, I want to run different stages according to the type of event that triggered the hook, but I can't find any variable giving me this event type. Is there a way to find it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you trigger the job with [Generic Webhook Trigger Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/generic-webhook-trigger-plugin/) you can resolve the **event** into a variable and use that in the pipeline.